# Auto-wiring property injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am trying to use property injection for StructureMap in a plug-in style system.

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(o => o.Scan(s =>
{
    s.AssembliesFromPath("path_to_assemblies");
    s.WithDefaultConventions();
});
```

Here is a sample implementation (purposely did not go deeper in defining T and TU as they are just simple classes)

```
public interface IBarService
{
    void Baz();
}

public class BarService : IBarService
{
    public void Baz() { /* implementation */ }
}


public abstract class PluginBase<T, TU> : IPlugin
    where T : AClass, new()
    where TU : BClass
{
     protected PluginBase()
     {
         //some init code in the constructor
     }
}

//Foo is created at run-time via Activator.CreateInstance()
public class FooPlugin : PluginBase<AClass, BClass>
{
   [SetterProperty]
   public IBarService BarService { get; set; }

   public void Fooey()
   {
       BarService.Baz();
   }
}
```

I want to auto-wire the property dependencies on all of these plug-ins that are created at run-time.  I thought I'd start out with property injection and then move things to the constructor if the need arose.

If I do:

```
var obj = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IBarService>();
```

anywhere in an instance of `FooPlugin`, I get the correct implementation and all is well.

If I do:

```
this.BarService.Baz();
```

I get a null reference exception because no instance of `IBarService` was set.

After I create my plug-in, if I do this:

`ObjectFactory.BuildUp(pluginObject)`.

All is well and `FooPlugin` has the correct implementation of `IBarService`.

Is there any way to simply allow me to decorate my plugin properties with `[SetterProperty]` and have StructureMap automatically inject those when the Plugin is created without having to call `ObjectFactory.BuildUp(pluginObject)` ?

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating your plugin instance in the cases where it doesn't work?  Are you just doing `new FooPlugin()`?

If you do var plugin = `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<PluginBase<AClass, BClass>>();`, do you get the plugin with all the correct dependencies resolved?

If you are instantiating the object with "new", the container has no way to know that the instance needs  dependencies resolved--it has no knowledge of that instance. Instances that need injected dependencies must be "managed by the container" so to speak.

Comment: All plugins in all circumstances are created via Activator.CreateInstance (with just a boolean in the constructor) after the assemblies are loaded at run-time.  I think I follow what you are saying -- I should be telling the container to resolve them once they are built).

Comment: Yep, the container doesn't know anything about your class, so it either needs to be the one to create the class, or you have to call BuildUp().

Answer (score 0):

You'll save yourself a lot of trouble if you just go the opposite route and inject all dependencies in the contstructor(s). This way there is a single place where you need to check if your objects are initialized properly...